# How to implement Voip call using xamarin forms(Cross Platform) like whatsapp call?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

We are developing a voice Chat application using Xamarin forms in visual studio 2017, We would like to try to implement very simple VoIP phone functionality in my Xamarin forms application, Now I am totally new in whole VoIP, For example I found this Xamarin forms github link http://www.linphone.org/snapshots/xamarin/, but this one is shared project using voip call, We always use to develope .NetStandered project so that anyone give me a link for linphone .Netstandered xamarin forms github otherwise what should I be looking for?, give me any suggestion to resolve this issue

Note: Sorry for my poor english

Comment: You can import package Ozeki voip sip client from NuGet.For more detail you can access http://www.ozekiphone.com/ozeki-voip-sip-client-997.html

Comment: Thank you for reply, i am working on it, if i have a any issue let you know

Comment: I am totally new in whole voip, please any one give me a  voip call with xamarin forms github

Comment: I tried CometChat and it is a paid service. They do not even offer trial version for testing. they want us to buy first